# How to force download to a client.. is printing on the browser

Tags: python, sockets, stream, httprequest

I'm trying to create something like a proxy(in PYTHON) to download and I'm getting a error. I want to force the user to download a file but instead is printing(the binary code) on the screen. Here is my code:
What I'm doing is... downloading a file from another server and at the same time trying to send this file to a client.
So is something like this: REMOTE_SERVER -> MY_SERVER -> CLIENT without having to save the file in my server. Does anyone could help what I'm doing wrong?

```
myfile = session.get(r.headers['location'], stream = True)
print "Content-Type: application/zip\r\n"
print "Prama: no-cache\r\n"
print "Expires: 0\r\n"
print "Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0\r\n"
print "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n"
print "Content-Type: application/download\r\n"
print "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=ternos.205.zip\r\n"
print "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n"
print "Content-Length: 144303765\r\n"

#print "Accept-Ranges: bytes\r\n"
print ("\r\n\r\n")
#with open('suits.zip', 'wb') as f:
for chunk in myfile.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
    if chunk:
        sys.stdout.write(chunk)
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

Seems that is nothing with the headers coz I've tried millions of different headers.. force-download, etc... but nothing happens..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print` *already* includes a newline in the output. Use `sys.stdout` instead, and write only *one* `Content-Type` header. After the headers, write only *one* more `\r\n` combo.

```
import sys

# ...
sys.stdout.write("Content-Type: application/zip\r\n")
sys.stdout.write("Prama: no-cache\r\n")
sys.stdout.write("Expires: 0\r\n")
sys.stdout.write("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0\r\n")
sys.stdout.write("Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n")
sys.stdout.write("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=ternos.205.zip\r\n")
sys.stdout.write("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n")
sys.stdout.write("Content-Length: 144303765\r\n")
sys.stdout.write("\r\n")
```

Most CGI implementations actually will translate regular `\n` to `\r\n` for you, so you *could* just print the headers *without* adding separators:

```
print "Content-Type: application/zip"
print "Prama: no-cache"
print "Expires: 0"
print "Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"
print "Content-Type: application/octet-stream"
print "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=ternos.205.zip"
print "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"
print "Content-Length: 144303765"
print
```

For then streaming the proxied request, I'd use the `.raw` file object and pass it through to `sys.stdout` with [`shutil.copyfileobj`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj):

```
import shutil

shutil.copyfileobj(myfile.raw, sys.stdout)
```

I doubt a flush is required, not if Python exits at that point and flushes `stdout` on close.

Comment: Still with the same problem... I tried million of things... as I am developing I am trying at localhost.. do you think that this might be the cause?

Comment: No, I don't think that makes a difference. Have you tried using a more manual tool to see what headers are being returned? What does `telnet localhost <portnumber>`, then `GET /path/to/script HTTP/1.0` plus double newline give you?

Comment: I just used tamper data and is not sending the headers... is returning a normal html header.. but at the same time I can't see any mistake in my headers

Comment: Just a second.. I just found that I left a content-type at the top of my page... I will try again and come back later

Comment: The HTTP server will add headers if your script doesn't provide them or not in the correct manner.

Comment: Dude, I got it.. is working now... thank you, thank you so much!